# How to capture several (delayed) output of a command to a file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm using a command uhd_find_devices to check the availability of a connected device and the output consists of 2 lines: the first showing the system infos, and the second showing the device after a delay, as following:

```
hanspond@hp-T430s:~$ uhd_find_devices
linux; GNU C++ version 5.4.0 20160609; Boost_105800; UHD_003.010.003.HEAD-0-gef157678

No UHD Devices Found
```

I want to capture both lines of output to a log-file.

But when I use`uhd_find_devices >> log-file`, only the first line can be logged to the file, the other line of output still pops up in the terminal.
What should be the correct way to do it?

Thank you !

Comment: 2nd line is written on stderr. Use `uhd_find_devices >> log-file 2>&1`

Comment: Thank you! That works. And how about if I just want to log the second line?